# jQuery $.post request failing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm sending a $.post request to php with jQuery. The jQuery code looks like this:

```
$('form').submit(function() {

    username = $('input[name="username"]').val();
    alert(username);
    $.post('/ajax/new_user.php', {username:username}, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });


});
```

In PHP, I'm just trying to do this for now:

```
<?php

echo $_POST['username'];

?>
```

The first alert in jQuery worked and prints the correct value, however the `alert(data)` always alerts and empty string ("").

The file path is correct. I'm doing many other AJAX requests on my site that work perfectly so I'm not sure what makes this one so different. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you inspect the XHR request in Firebug or Chrome's debugger and find out what the response from your server is?

Comment: Also, try an echo "hello world" in the PHP, to see if the problem is with retrieving the $_POST param.

Comment: Did you edit the **correct** `new_user.php` file and did you save it?

Comment: Maybe {username:"username"} and then check if PHP really is passing anything. Have a `echo "something"` on php just to be sure it is not returning blank.

Comment: Echoing a 'hello world' failed, and when I looked at the XHR request it showed "Status: aborted" and the URL was "POST new_user.php" so what does that mean?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but if you have a bigger form, i think it's a good idea to use this kind of plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Comment: i'm not sure, but shouldn't you be returning false at the end of the submit() ? I usually don't attach the submit() event to the form, but to the submit button itself via click().

Comment: Wow...I feel like an idiot. That solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So. The answer was adding a

```
return false;
```

at the end of the submit() event.

Comment: Nice catch! I can't believe I didn't see something so obvious q:

Answer (score 1):

should not

```
 $.post('/ajax/new_user.php', {username:username}, function(data) { 
        alert(data); 
    });
```

be

```
 $.post('/ajax/new_user.php', {"username":username}, function(data) { 
        alert(data); 
    });
```

Comment: Just for the record, that's a somewhat common misconception.  The first example is a perfectly valid object literal, which can be used anywhere in your client side code.  It's not, however, valid JSON (which is what you fixed in the second example).  Having valid JSON is primarily important when you're rendering it to a response that will be consumed/parsed as a JSON service (or similar)...

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
{username:username}
```

with

```
{'username':username}
```

If that doesn't work, replace the contents on your PHP file with:

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);

?>
```

So you can see if you're even getting the data.

Comment: What's the output of the print_r?

Comment: The print_r() just does the same thing, and when I navigate to the PHP file directly, it shows Array()

Answer (score 0):

Pixeline's comment solved my problem, all I had to do was `return false` at the end of the submit.